# \n error when exporting MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Good morning,

Today I'm trying to export my MySQL database to import it to another MySQL database because I'm moving a domain to a different server, but something weird is happening: my table contains returns (\n) and when I export it, the returns become \n, and then when I import it, the \n character is imported in my table and instead of having the return displayed in the cell, I have the \n character.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem? Due to this issue, my applications don't read correctly the cells and my website is not working.

I can provide images:

**original:**

[image]

**new (with the \n error):**

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone is having this issue, i just exported the database in XML instead of SQL. That way it ignores the break line.

Regards.